# Printer can write into laptop folder

Tags: wifi, security, scanning

Well that was surprising.  And a little alarming.

I got a new multifunction printer, a Canon MG7120.  It is connected wirelessly to my home local area network.  I installed the latest drivers from the Canon website.  I scanned some pages using the scan operation on the printer and selected my laptop and my username on the laptop as where to put the scans.  I expected to be asked for a sign-in or something to get access to the laptop.

I got nothing, and the operation seemed to complete.  My laptop was in the other room, and when I looked at it, the scans (in a PDF) had been deposited into my Pictures folder, *and* a new Finder window had been opened with scan PDF file highlighted!

How did the printer do that?  Does the printer driver have a back door that lets the printer write into my user account?  Or did I create some other sort of back door when I installed the drivers?  Or did I open the door myself somehow?  Is this a security hole?

I am using a relatively new Time Capsule (the taller than wide version) to create my local network, and the laptop is a 2012 MacBook Air.

Comment: When you installed the printer driver on your laptop, did it ask you for permissions?

Comment: Mark, please can you share the listening network sockets using the `lsof` command mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x Knowing the listening socket details will help track down how the scanner could access your MacBook Air. It does sound like Canon have opened up additional access, but let's check and confirm if and how.

Comment: When installing the driver, it asked me for my password (which I'm sure had to be an admin password), as has every driver installation I have done.  It did not ask me anything like: "Can we install a backdoor to allow our devices to write files on your laptop whenever they feel like?"

Comment: `/Applications/Canon Utilities/IJ Scan Utility/Canon IJ Scan Utility2.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/CIJSUAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/CIJSUAgent` is listening on `UDP *:63515`.